# Encoding works in Debug but otherwise not

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, encoding

I have a webapp running with Tomcat. the Tomcat is configured to use UTF8.
I get a value in a `ServletRequest` object (request). The special characters in a parameter (`request.getParameter("Signer")`) are replaced by a question mark.

There is a filter class (`@WebFilter`) where the params are processed.
When doing a debug in Eclipse I get the right value with correct characters.
When running the same process without debugging the characters are replaced by a question mark.

There is no difference. Just by debugging I get the wanted results.

I checked that the Tomcat is configured to handle UTF8 parameters.

I have no control over the programm providing the paramters.

Comment: You mean you get different results for Eclipse/Run vs. Eclipse/Debug?

Comment: No, it's a webapp and I just call the Login url to start it. The different behaviour is seen when adding a breakpoint in the doFilter Method of the class annotated with @WebFilter.

Comment: Well, the questionmark is the [Unicode Replacement Character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character), meaning that the request contains some other encoding than `UTF-8`. However since debugging (or rather hitting a breakpoint) [should not affect that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug), there has to be some difference somewhere. How are you observing the results in both cases?

Comment: I can see the difference
1) in the Eclipse console (I added System.out.println)
2) In the browser
3) in the data base where the results are stored


So, it's definitely not a problem of viewing the data...

Comment: Maybe you need to show the code in your filter class. You might want to look at the network traffic to see what encoding is used. It's a GET request right?

Comment: To make things easier I simplified the code in the filter class. Same behaviour. But I think it's a post request.

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

   chain.doFilter(request, response);
}

Comment: Well, I don't have any good ideas left to give you (except for the network traffic capturing thing, just in case). Good luck and let me know if you solve it.

Comment: It could be a problem viewing the code in that the font being used has to support that character.

Comment: Not really. Also checked the results in the browser (the rendered web page) and the data base.